# Перезагрузка страницы JS при пустом input

Tags: javascript, settimeout, reload

Всем привет, мне нужно сделать зациклить перезагрузку страницы, если input пустой. Сейчас делается перезагрузка только после нажатия кнопки.
Что в моём коде сделано не так?
Вот код: Js

````
```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form-bt').on('click', function(){
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var comment = $('#comment').val();
            
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: { 
                    username: username,
                    comment: comment,
                }
            })

            window.location.reload(1);

        })
        if($('#username').val() == ' '){
            var t = setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.reload(1);
            }, 5000);
        }else{
            clearTimeout(t);
        }

        

        
        
    });
```
````

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Надо написать:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if($('#username').val().trim() === '')
        window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

вне функции клика

Comment: Почему не `window.location.href = window.location.href`?

Comment: Спасибо -за помощь!

Comment: @ΝNL993 это бессмысленная запись)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поддержка старых браузеров.

Comment: @ΝNL993 каких? chrome 0?))